# Linked Combobox

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

Is it possible to have the same combobox appear on multiple forms with linked selections?

I have several forms used for data entry and on the Main form (which has links to the other forms) there are two comboboxes, one queries Year and the other Branch. Based on the selections of these two combo boxes the other forms with apply filters on activate so that users can enter data for their specific branches.

What I am trying to do is have the same comboboxes appear on all the forms so that users don't have to go back to the main form to change the year or branch.

Comment: I don't see why you could not add two ComboBoxes to these forms linked to the same query. What is the exact problem you run into when you add them to the children forms?

Answer (score 0):

What you're saying is this:
On Form A the user would choose the year and the branch.
On form B their selection would continue to appear.
Option 1: If they can change it in form B you need to copy the value (set the default value) when you launch form B.
Option 2: if they can't change it in form B just put the value inside a (locked) text box, so they will see what the year was but they wouldn't be able to change it.

Comment: Option 1 is what I'm looking for. I was hoping there was some built in functionality for this as having each sheet update like you suggest may get messy.

Comment: Then in the default value for Form B as the value from Form A. in the properties sheet -> default value -> [forms]![FromA]![cmbBox]